# Editable data table display in Python

Tags: python, datatable

I have a python (2.7) script that reads incoming data over a serial port in the following form:

```
ID: 648 Data: 45 77 33 9C 26 9A 1F 42
ID: 363 Data: 35 74 36 BC 26 9D 
...
```

The data stream contains several different ID's (about 30) that repeat periodically with 2-8 data bytes. The frequency of the ID's ranges from 10-120 ms. Some ID's repeat sooner than others.

Anyway, I have a basic python script that reads this stream into 2 variables, (id and data):

```
import serial
import re

ser = serial.Serial("COM11", 115200)

while 1:
    reading = ser.readline()
    matchObj = re.match( r'ID:\s([0-9A-F]+)\sData:\s([^\n]+)', reading, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj:
        id = matchObj.group(1)
        data = matchObj.group(2)
    else:
        print "No match!!"
```

What I want to do is display this data in real time in a data table format where new ID entries are added to the table and repeated ID entries are updated. This would result in a table that would initially grow with the discovery of the ID's, then update as the data for the ID's changed.

I have seen some examples of table modules that let you add rows to a table, but I also need to be able to modify existing entries as that is what will be happening most often.

I am still pretty new with python and I need an implementation that does not have excessive overhead to keep the data updating as fast as possible.

Any thoughts??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) is the go-to for terminal displays.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import curses
import time

def updater():
    fakedata = [[1, 78], [2, 97], [1, 45], [2, 2], [3, 89]]
    codes_to_linenums_dict = {}
    last_line = 0
    win = curses.initscr()
    for code, data in fakedata:
        try:
            # if we haven't seen this code before, give it the next line
            if code not in codes_to_linenums_dict:
                codes_to_linenums_dict[code] = last_line
                last_line += 1
            # use the line we set for this code.
            line = codes_to_linenums_dict[code]
            win.addstr(line, 0, '{}: {}    '.format(code, data))
            win.refresh()
            # For display only
            time.sleep(2)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # if endwin isn't called the terminal becomes unuseable.
            curses.endwin()
            raise
    curses.endwin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater()
```

~

Comment: Looked really promising, but there is no windows version??